# Keyup event giving an event with undefined properties

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a 'keyup' event on a textarea. When I try `console.log(ev)` I see a proper event, but when I try to use the event's properties, I see nothing but the `isTrusted` property (and others like `keycode` yield `undefined`).

```
el.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
})
```

Result:

```
keyup { target: textarea#foo, key: "Enter", charCode: 0, keyCode: 13 }
```

Whereas:

```
el.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ev));
})
```

yields

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

The event apparently is not properly filled up when the listener is called, and only gets filled later (and when the object is logged to the console, it shows the correct updated version). I've seen some objects updating after the fact in the console, but I've never seen an unfilled event in an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the event isn't fully-populated, it's that [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) only includes **own, enumerable** properties (and only ones with string Object., not symbol keys), not inherited ones. Some of those properties are inherited from `Event`, so they aren't own properties.

If you want to see all properties, including inherited ones and non-enumerable ones, you can do that with a combination of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `Object.getOwnPropertysymbols` (if you want symbol-named properties), and `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");
el.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    showAllProperties(e);
});

function showAllProperties(obj) {
    const result = {};
    let currentObj = obj;
    while (currentObj !== null && currentObj !== Object.prototype) {
        for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(currentObj)) {
            if (!(key in result)) {
                let value = obj[key]; // Must be `obj`, not `currentObj`!
                switch (typeof value) {
                    case "object":
                        value = value === null ? "null" : "(an object)";
                        break;
                    case "function":
                        value = "(a function)";
                        break;
                }
                console.log({ key, value });
            }
        }
        currentObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(currentObj);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

> and others like `keycode` yield undefined

It's [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) (with a capital `C`). (It's also deprecated, see [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or depending on what you want, [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)).)

Comment: So my investigation method was incorrect. Turns out I forgot the capital C in `keyCode`. Thanks !